# Links are disabled when return to TabView using routerExtension.back() - NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm using Nativescript with Typescript/Angular for Android, I am working on TabView where I am able to navigate to next/sub page, while return by `routerExtension.back()` or `routerExtension.backToPreviousPage()` all the link are disabled in page-router-outlet, but router-outlet working fine. If I use to return via `routerExtension.navigate(['/tabs'])` able to see all the links.

Versions:

```
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
"@nativescript/schematics": "^1.0.0",
"nativescript-angular": "~8.21.0",
```

I followed this tutorial, https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation.

I just started working on nativescript.

Comment: Can you setup a Playground sample to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children
JS: Error: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children
JS:     at new ZoneAwareError

Comment: Trying to setup a playground file and send you soon. meanwhile if possible to figure the issue with this 'error msg' mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=3xlsyH, playground i created. Seems, It also have an issue previewing.

Comment: While using multiple outlets, your nsRouterLink should include path for each outlet.

Comment: yes, but nsRouterLink is working fine. The issue is with routerExtension.back() and routerExtension.backToPreviousPage() when navigating back to TabView page and also if I use router-outlet in TabView router instead of page-router-outlet seems working only problem is menu content is not changing as per the Tab. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: It's kind of chain reaction, you can not compare outlet and page router outlet they are completely different.

Comment: okay. any solution, why am i getting the error? I am using page-router-outlet and routerExtension.back(), when return to tabview route all the links are disabled in tabview page and getting ERROR: Cannot reattach ActivatedRouteSnapshot with a different number of children

Comment: That's the solution, you have to mention each outlet in your link either in HTML template or using Controller - like you do in `tab-view-challenge.component`.

Comment: But, it works as I expected in a tutorial.

Comment: If you check the comments below, you can already see people reporting similar issues and solution was same. It tutorial is year and half old, there had been numerous updates.